# Как сделать автопрокрутку для этого слайдера

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="http://silverbox.kz/mg-templates/default/images/1.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="http://silverbox.kz/mg-templates/default/images/2.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="http://silverbox.kz/mg-templates/default/images/3.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="http://silverbox.kz/mg-templates/default/images/4.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="http://silverbox.kz/mg-templates/default/images/5.jpg" alt=""></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".slider").each(function () { // обрабатываем каждый слайдер
  var obj = $(this);
  $(obj).append("<div class='nav'></div>");
  $(obj).find("li").each(function () {
   $(obj).find(".nav").append("<span rel='"+$(this).index()+"'></span>"); // добавляем блок навигации
   $(this).addClass("slider"+$(this).index());
  });
  $(obj).find("span").first().addClass("on"); // делаем активным первый элемент меню
 });
});
function sliderJS (obj, sl) { // slider function
 var ul = $(sl).find("ul"); // находим блок
 var bl = $(sl).find("li.slider"+obj); // находим любой из элементов блока
 var step = $(bl).width(); // ширина объекта
 $(ul).animate({marginLeft: "-"+step*obj}, 500); // 500 это скорость перемотки
}
$(document).on("click", ".slider .nav span", function() { // slider click navigate
 var sl = $(this).closest(".slider"); // находим, в каком блоке был клик
 $(sl).find("span").removeClass("on"); // убираем активный элемент
 $(this).addClass("on"); // делаем активным текущий
 var obj = $(this).attr("rel"); // узнаем его номер
 sliderJS(obj, sl); // слайдим
 return false;
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
 .slider {
 z-index: 9;
 width: 700px;
 height: 290px;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: 0 0 7px;
 position: relative;
 }
 .slider ul,
 .slider li {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 list-style-type: none;
 }
 .slider ul {
 width: 9999px; 
 }
 .slider ul li {
 list-style-type: none;
 float: left;
 width: 700px;
 height: 290px;
 }
 .slider .nav {
 position: absolute;
 left: 15px;
 bottom: 12px; 
 }
 .slider .nav span {
 opacity: 0.9;
 background: #fff;
 margin: 0 8px 0 0;
 width: 16px;
 height: 16px;
 border-radius: 8px;
 cursor: pointer;
 overflow: hidden;
 display: block;
 float: left;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #000;
 }
 .slider .nav span.on {
 background: #2e9419;
 }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Для любого автоматического действия лучше всего использовать http://javascript.ru/setinterval

То, что написано в «клике» опишите в интервал, задайте время, ???? профит.